# Setting something in DB only once

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using a setInterval to detect a value I get from my PLC(Programmable logic controller) When it is `1` it executes a PHP page that inserts data in my MYSQL database.

So when I'm holding my button down for longer than 1 second, it sets the DB values multiple times in it.

Below you can find my code:

```
var Axo800RstBtn;

setInterval(function()
{
    Axo800RstBtn = document.getElementById('Axo800BtnStatus').innerHTML;
    var BatchUnits1 = document.getElementById('Axo800BatchProduction').innerHTML;

    if(Axo800RstBtn == 1)
    {   
        $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "SetBatchProductionInDB.php",
        data: { 
                machineNumber: 1,
                actualProduction: BatchUnits1 
              }     
        })
        .done(function(msg)
        {
            console.log("Bericht: " + msg);
        })
    }
},1250);
```

Is there a way to tell my page it can only execute once per 1 minute? some kind of block. Or maybe a block on the execute query?

Comment: Where is the button click event in all of this?

Comment: The button value is set in the `Axo800BtnStatus` `div`. As I said it's a value from my PLC. It has a webserver, and I use a function to get the information in that `div`.

Comment: Checking the button every 1.25 seconds seems like a poor solution. If the interval has just happened when the user clicks you're idling for over a second for no reason before you do anything. Why can't you set up a listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do the trick:

```
var Axo800RstBtn;
var hasBeenSet = false;

setInterval(function()
{
    Axo800RstBtn = document.getElementById('Axo800BtnStatus').innerHTML;
    var BatchUnits1 = document.getElementById('Axo800BatchProduction').innerHTML;

    if(Axo800RstBtn == 1 && !hasBeenSet)
    {   

        hasBeenSet = true;

        $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "SetBatchProductionInDB.php",
        data: { 
                machineNumber: 1,
                actualProduction: BatchUnits1 
              }     
        })
        .done(function(msg)
        {
            console.log("Bericht: " + msg);
        })
    }
},1250);
```

Although I would strongly advise that you also do this control server-side. I.E. you could keep track of the script being called by setting up a session var in PHP.

This code will prevent the request from being sent as soon as the request has been sent once. If you want to enable it after 60 seconds you could add after hasBeenSet = true;

```
hasBeenSet = true;
setTimeout(function(){ hasBeenSet = false}, 60000);
```

Comment: @MonsieurPixel Ah that's exactly what I want! Thanks alot! this works perfectly. I say something about the `setTimeout`, but I didn't know how it exactly worked. Thanks again for the help!